# Rails Mailer Best Practice - controller or after_create callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

In common Ruby on Rails 3/4 apps, there are two options to deliver mail after the creation of a model:

**1) Send the mail directly from the controller's create action**

```
#listings_controller.rb

def create
    @listing.create(params[:listing])
    if @listing.save
        ListingMailer.new_listing_notice(@listing).deliver
        format.html {redirect_to @listing}
        ...
    end
end
```

or **2) Send the mail from a Model Callback**

```
#listing.rb


class Listing
    after_create :notify
    ...
    def notify
        ListingMailer.new_listing_notice(self).deliver
    end
end
```

Is there a current consensus about which way is better? Sending from the controller gives more control, but if a mail will always be sent is there any reason not to use the callback? Is this mostly a question of style, or are there other important concerns?

Comment: Sending an email is a matter of context. So not in model, please. Check this approach: https://github.com/krisleech/wisper

Comment: Example of the absurdity of emails in models: you import a csv with users, would send them an email to thank them for registering? Context...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally, it's much more difficult to maintain code that has `after_*` hooks in models. There are, of course some cases, when using a callback is very reasonable (computing a checksum, for instance, should be done all the time in some applications), but those cases are exceptions to the rule.

In your example with the email, here's some drawbacks of the callback approach:

#### The mailer interface and the Listing model change for different reasons ([Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

For instance, you would like your emails to be sent using a special queue. The interface of communicating with the queue should not, in any way, affect the way the Listing model is built.

#### Your application doesn't need emailing all the time.

Emailing is just one of the means of interacting with the outside world. Not all of the business logic will always require to be tied to the outside world. One of the examples, as [apneadiving](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350087/apneadiving) mentioned is import. Another example is the console interface (would you like to be sent an email when you're playing with the rails console?)

#### Testing is difficult.

This is more of a result of 1 and 2, but testing `after` hooks is increasingly difficult as time passes. The need of mocking the mailer while testing the Listing model makes the test unclear and more difficult to maintain whenever something changes.

Comment: I am using ColdFusion/CFWheels (Ruby on Rails analog framework) but i think my question might still be okay... If we only send mail via a controller, what should be done if (e.g.) a Comments controller creates a new person (new user created automatically when submitting a comment) - like a signup form in the People controller, but still needs same welcome email?  I'll have to remember to send out a welcome message in a controller that may know nothing about the rules for People, which seems... not good. How should I refactor so that "Comments" doesn't have to know so much about People?