# Best Practices in Rails 5 for calling ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I'm building a Rails 5 app which will need to send emails like invites and notifications...

Models: `Invite.rb, Notification.rb`

What is the current recommendation/best-practice for where in a rails app implementation for mailers (.deliver) should take place?

Should .deliver happen with a model's callback like `after_create`?

Comment: You can also use after_save. But here you need to identify if the record is new record or existing record. 
if you just want to send mail only after creating a new record. You are good to deliver mail in after_create.

Comment: I should send mailers in the Controller? The Model? Somewhere else? What is the Rails recommendation?

Comment: When we built a app in rails I called MailSender.deliver from the model only. This i see the most followed practice in rails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Mailer Best Practice - controller or after\_create callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797799/rails-mailer-best-practice-controller-or-after-create-callback)

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to deliver a mail in ActiveRecord callback functions. This can lead to all kinds of weird scenarios when updating a record and then an email gets accidentally sent to a user.

The best place depends on the scenario.

*Scenario 1*: An email gets triggered when an end-point in your app is hit.

Solution: It is ok to have this triggered in the controller or a [service object](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) or [interactor](https://goiabada.blog/interactors-in-ruby-easy-as-cake-simple-as-pie-33f66de2eb78) depending on which abstraction makes sense. Also, when this happens via a request, we want quick response times. It is advisable to rather use the `deliver_later` in ActionMailer

*Scenario 2*: An email gets triggered via a rake-task or script

Solution: It is ok to have the email directly in the rake task or script